# Mapping through icons from json data fetched from database doesn't seem to be displaying icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, font-awesome

I have a terms and conditions table in the database, so far I have successfully mapped the conditions but for some reason the icons aren't showing

```
        <Layout>
            <div className='container bg-white mx-auto border rounded p-4 lg:w-1/2'>
            {data.map((term) => {
              const {condition, icon} = term;
        
              
            return (

              <div key={term.id}  className='p-2 flex flex-row text-md'>
              <div className='w-4 h-4'>
                {console.log(icon)}
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon}  />
              </div>
              <h3 className='mx-2'>{condition}</h3>
              </div>
              
              );

            })}
            </div>
        </Layout>
```

And also if you're wondering if the icon variable is valid here is a picture of the console log

[Console log of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VohHG.png)

You see when I manually type faUser the  shows, but now its not showing anything at all..

I tried to map icons from database expecting them to show, but ended up with white spaces instead.

Comment: Fontawesome icon is like `fa-user` [Check here](https://fontawesome.com/icons/user?s=solid&f=classic)

Comment: You may want to review the [Fontawesome React docs](https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/use-with/react/add-icons) as your code doesn't seem to match their examples.